# how to extract bold text from a pdf using R

Tags: r, pdf

I have searched through SO and the closest I got to the answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49536590/1972786).
But my requirement is to get a simpler & more elegant way to extract bold from a simple paragraph of text of pdf. The `pdftools` package only extracts the plain text component. Does anyone know if there is any other way to simply detect bold tokens (or words) from a chunk of text in pdf. I use R so kindly restrict to suggestions in R.

Comment: _"Please don't advice possibly using a particular tool because I am unwilling to do the work necessary to setup a usable data science environment"_ is not exactly going to cause folks to come running to this question. Thousands of R folks manage to have a working R + rJava environment. It has some headaches. Ultimately it's worth it b/c you get access to a whole world of great Java libraries. Anyway, not going to bother with a full answer but https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pdfbox/ can likely help (but there's that rJava "work" again).

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF?

Comment: Thank you for direct the advice @hrbrmstr. I get what you are trying to say. Apologise for sounding lazy.  I will check your link and also try to setup an rJava environment. I guess what I am also understanding, reading in between your lines, is that `rJava` is essential for a data science environment if I use R. Am I correct?

Comment: @RalfStubner: I use the pdf on this [link here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sluy0bcz0lfpmgw/Mulla__Indian_Contract_Act2018-11-12_01-00.PDF?dl=0). Although it is a bit large it has all its titles in bold hence is an ideal case of text processing using bold titles as section headers. If you can suggest any easy way (not intending to be lazy but if there's an easier way I would be happy to use it).

Comment: So your actual aim is not “identify bold text” but “identify section titles “?

Comment: You are right @ralf. The bold text could be just one way to identify section headings. Could you suggest any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on answers received from @hrbmstr and @ralf. So thanks to them. I've made the answers simpler (mainly taking out the peculiarity of the HTML conversion & file naming). Also it is tailored for MAC OS users (perhaps LINUX too) - not sure about Windows guys.

I presume you have `pdftohtml` installed on your machine. If not use `brew install pdftohtml`. If you donot have **homebrew** on your MAC then install it first. A link is provided to help you [for homebrew](https://brewinstall.org/Install-pdftohtml-on-Mac-with-Brew/).

Once you are sure `pdftohtml` is installed on the mac, go with this R function to extract bold from any pdf document.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# pass a pdf file in current directory to this function
extr_bold <- function(file) {
  basefile <- str_remove(file,"\\.pdf|\\.PDF")
  htmlfile <- paste0(basefile,"s",".html")
  if(!exists(htmlfile) ) 
    system2("pdftohtml",args = c("-i",file),stdout=NULL)
  nodevar <- read_html(htmlfile)
  x <- html_nodes(nodevar,xpath = ".//b")
  html_text(x)
}
```

Comment: @hrbmstr: could you please check my answer and see if it makes sense? Or does it need some improvement without adding complexity and of course keeping it easy to read. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Along with having a flexible toolkit, data science regularly requires out-of-the-box thinking (at least in my profession).

#### But, first, a thing about PDF files.

I don't think they are what you think they are. "Bold" (or "italic", etc.) isn't "metadata". You should spend some time reading up on PDF files because they are complex, nasty, evil things that you are likely to encounter often when working with data. Read this — https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777953/1457051 — to see what finding bold text actually entails (follow the link to the 1.8.x Java `pdfbox` solution).

#### Back to our irregularly scheduled answering

While I'm one of the YUGEst proponents of R, not *everything* needs to be done or should be done in R. Sure, we'll use R to *eventually* get your **bold** text but we'll use a helper command-line utility to do so.

The `pdftools` package is based on the [`poppler`](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) library. It comes with the source so "I'm just an R user" folks likely don't have the full `poppler` toolset on their system.

Mac folks can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to (once you get Homebrew setup):

- `brew install poppler`

Linux folks know how to do things. Windows folks are lost forever (there *are* poppler binaries for you, but your time would be better spent switching to a real operating system).

Once you do that, you can use the below to achieve your goal.

First, we'll make a helper function with lots of safety bumpers:

```
#' Uses the command-line pdftohtml function from the poppler library
#' to convert a PDF to HTML and then read it in with xml2::read_html()
#'
#' @md
#' @param path the path to the file [path.expand()] will be run on this value
#' @param extra_args extra command-line arguments to be passed to `pdftohtml`.
#'        They should be supplied as you would supply arguments to the `args`
#'        parameter of [system2()].
read_pdf_as_html <- function(path, extra_args=character()) {

  # make sure poppler/pdftohtml is installed
  pdftohtml <- Sys.which("pdftohtml")
  if (pdftohtml == "") {
    stop("The pdftohtml command-line utility must be installed.", call.=FALSE)
  }

  # make sure the file exists
  path <- path.expand(path)
  stopifnot(file.exists(path))

  # pdf's should really have a PDF extension
  stopifnot(tolower(tools::file_ext(path)) == "pdf")

  # get by with a little help from our friends
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(xml2, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
    library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
  })

  # we're going to do the conversion in a temp directory space
  td <- tempfile(fileext = "_dir")
  dir.create(td)
  on.exit(unlink(td, recursive=TRUE), add=TRUE)

  # save our current working directory
  curwd <- getwd()
  on.exit(setwd(curwd), add=TRUE)

  # move to the temp space
  setwd(td)
  file.copy(path, td)

  # collect the extra arguments
  c(
    "-i" # ignore images
  ) -> args

  args <- c(args, extra_args, basename(path), "r-doc") # saves it to r-doc-html.html

  # this could take seconds so inform users what's going on
  message("Converting ", basename(path), "...")

  # we'll let stderr display so you can debug errors
  system2(
    command = pdftohtml,
    args = args,
    stdout = TRUE
  ) -> res

  res <- gsub("^Page-", "", res[length(res)])
  message("Converted ", res, " pages")

  # this will need to be changed if poppler ever does anything different
  xml2::read_html("r-docs.html")

}
```

Now, we'll use it:

```
doc <- read_pdf_as_html("~/Data/Mulla__Indian_Contract_Act2018-11-12_01-00.PDF")

bold_tags <- html_nodes(doc, xpath=".//b")

bold_words <- html_text(bold_tags)

head(bold_words, 20)
##  [1] "Preamble"                                                                                   
##  [2] "WHEREAS it is expedient to define and amend certain parts of the law relating to contracts;"
##  [3] "History"                                                                                    
##  [4] "Ancient and Medieval Period"                                                                
##  [5] "The Introduction of English Law Into India"                                                 
##  [6] "Mofussal Courts"                                                                            
##  [7] "Legislation"                                                                                
##  [8] "The Indian Contract Act 1872"                                                               
##  [9] "The Making of the Act"                                                                      
## [10] "Law of Contract Until 1950"                                                                 
## [11] "The Law of Contract after 1950"                                                             
## [12] "Amendments to This Act"                                                                     
## [13] "Other Laws Affecting Contracts and Enforcement"                                             
## [14] "Recommendations of the Indian Law Commission"                                               
## [15] "Section 1."                                                                                 
## [16] "Short title"                                                                                
## [17] "Extent, Commencement."                                                                      
## [18] "Enactments Repealed."                                                                       
## [19] "Applicability of the Act"                                                                   
## [20] "Scheme of the Act"

length(bold_words)
## [1] 1939
```

No Java required at all and you've got your **bold words**.

If you do want to go the `pdfbox-app` route as Ralf noted, you can use this wrapper to make it easier to work with:

```
read_pdf_as_html_with_pdfbox <- function(path) {

  java <- Sys.which("java")
  if (java == "") {
    stop("Java binary is not on the system PATH.", call.=FALSE)
  }

  # get by with a little help from our friends
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(httr, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
    library(xml2, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
    library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
  })

  path <- path.expand(path)
  stopifnot(file.exists(path))

  # pdf's should really have a PDF extension
  stopifnot(tolower(tools::file_ext(path)) == "pdf")

  # download the pdfbox "app" if not installed
  if (!dir.exists("~/.pdfboxjars")) {
    message("~/.pdfboxjars not found. Creating it and downloading pdfbox-app jar...")
    dir.create("~/.pdfboxjars")
    httr::GET(
      url = "http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.12/pdfbox-app-2.0.12.jar",
      httr::write_disk(file.path("~/.pdfboxjars", "pdfbox-app-2.0.12.jar")),
      httr::progress()
    ) -> res
    httr::stop_for_status(res)
  }

  # we're going to do the conversion in a temp directory space
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  on.exit(unlink(tf), add=TRUE)

  c(
    "-jar",
    path.expand(file.path("~/.pdfboxjars", "pdfbox-app-2.0.12.jar")),
    "ExtractText",
    "-html",
    path,
    tf
  ) -> args

  # this could take seconds so inform users what's going on
  message("Converting ", basename(path), "...")

  system2(
    command = java,
    args = args
  ) -> res

  xml2::read_html(tf)

}
```

Comment: @hrbmstr : thank you so much. I have started the process of implementation. Seems there is something amiss in the `pdftohtml` command. After homebrewing `poppler` (went through successfully on Mac OS Mujave) and creating all the temp directory, copying the pdf file there etc the pdftohtml seems to return a status = 1.  `Warning message:
In system2(command = "pdftohtml", args = args, stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''pdftohtml' -i' had status 1`;     Please note I have not supplied extra_args to pdftohtm. The args  = "-i" was only used.

Comment: Try running it without the function. In a terminal, try just `pdftohtml -i thenameofyourpdffile.pdf` and then a `read_html` on the file that has an `s` towards the end.

Comment: I managed to convert the pdf to html using the command `pdftohtml -i file.pdf` followed by `bold_tags <- html_nodes(doc, xpath=".//b"); bold_words <- html_text(bold_tags)` but the variable `bold_words` is a `0` length character vector.

Comment: Can you add what you did and the exact (complete with library calls) R code after that to the original question?

Comment: Bingo it's working! I was using the incorrect html file out of the three files formed by default. Also, I suggest we simplify the answer for others. I have made this simple function that delivers the output without adding too many checks.

Comment: I fully support and encourage you to write that up as an answer and I'll be one of the first if not the first up-votes for it. Then (I forget how long you have to wait) you can also accept it. You did alot of work and ultimately came up with the answer and I think you deserve the points for it.

Answer (score 3):

**JUNE 2021 UPDATED ANSWER**

I think this question needs an updated answer.

**GOOD NEWS**: The R package `pdftools` has included in its recent update the option to extract `font-data` from the pdfs. The function `pdf_data` has now an additional argument `font_info` described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/blob/master/man/pdftools.Rd):

> **font_info** if TRUE, extract font-data for each box. Be careful, this
> requires a very recent version of poppler and will error otherwise.

A simple implementation using `pdftools::pdf_data` with `font_info=TRUE` shows that:

```
pdftools::pdf_data(pdf = "https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.10582.pdf", font_info = TRUE)
```

[image]

**REMARKS:**

1. Some **bold** fonts are indicated by suffixes of medium fonts (Medi) as in e.g., `KBJWLM+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi`.
2. The *italics* are indicated by suffixes like `ReguItal` which stands for 'Regular Italics'. For example, `ZBSJXS+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal`.
3. Regular fonts are obviously indicated by purely `Regu` suffixes as in `VDTZKA+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu`.

**WARNING:** This answer has never been tested for pdf images (scanned) with overlapped/overlayed text.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `tabularizer`, but I don't know a way that does not involve Java. I had hoped that Apache Tika via the `rtika` package can be used. However, [bold text is not rendered as such](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2708). However, one can use [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) as shown in that ticket:

```
 java -jar <pdfbox-jar> ExtractText -html <pdf-file> <html-file>
```

This command would normally started in a shell, but you can also use `system(2)` from within R. Then in R use

```
html <- xml2::read_html(<html-file>)
bold <- xml2::xml_find_all(html, '//b')
head(xml2::xml_contents(bold))
```

to process the HTML file.
With your document this returns

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] Preamble\n
[2] WHEREAS it is expedient to define and amend certain parts of the law relating to contracts;\n
[3] History\n
[4] Ancient and Medieval Period\n
[5] The Introduction of English Law Into India\n
[6] Mofussal Courts\n
```

Comment: I think Ralf your answer uses java hence I am not trying it out of now. Also, the remaining parts seem to be the same as @hrbmstr. So thanks a lot. I am now replicating my working function as a new answer so that others who search on this (including myself) donot get stuck by selecting the incorrect html file.