# Extract bold and underlined texts from .pdf

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I need to extract text from pdf. But the pdf has some bold and underlined texts. I tried MyPDF2 but getting error while trying to read those pdfs containing formatted texts.

```
    import PyPDF2
    pdf_file = open('Downloads/th.pdf','rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    print (page_content)
```

**Output**

```
    ˘ˇˆˆ˝˛˚˜ ˜˚!˘˘ˇˆ˙˛˝˚˜˚ !ˆ"#$ˆ%&'˛"˝#$%˝˚'(˚˛)˛˝*+!-.$ˆ˚˛˚˛˘/˛˛0˛122/ 
    ˘˛˘˚˘˚2ˆ$".#$ˆ%˘˛˛$ˆ$%#$ˆ%˛˛˛˛˝˝(0/ 0$%˙˚˙3#"$˘--4˛0˚! 
    ˆ"#$ˆ%56272˛ˇ5'˛6222˛'4˘8(9˛(˜˚˛&˙˙˙˙˙
```

Comment: what did you try?  can you post code?  what was the error?  did you really mean MyPDF2?  I've used **P**yPDF2 with Python before…

Comment: I don't know with underlined texts but with regards to **bold** fonts, try this updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398611/how-to-extract-bold-text-from-a-pdf-using-r/67963468#67963468 which the free software R.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Python 3.6 and the PyPDF2 moduele:

1. [Get and install Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Install PyPDF2 module using PIP. Run in terminal (or CMD/PowerShell in windows): pip install PyPDF2
3. Run this code in the python console as in the [tutorial](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/), for reading the PDF file and extracting the text:

   ```
   import PyPDF2        
   pdfFileObj = open('meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')        
   pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)        
   pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)        
   pageObj.extractText()
   ```

Comment: thanks. but i used the same code. but texts are bold and underlined and i am getting the output like this

output:

˘ˇˆˆ˝˛˚˜ ˜˚!˘˘ˇˆ˙˛˝˚˜˚ !ˆ"#$ˆ%&'˛"˝#$%˝˚'(˚˛)˛˝*+!-.$ˆ˚˛˚˛˘/˛˛0˛122/˘˛˘˚˘˚2ˆ$".#$ˆ%˘˛˛$ˆ$%#$ˆ%˛˛˛˛˝˝(0/ 0$%˙˚˙3#"$˘--4˛0˚!ˆ"#$ˆ%56272˛ˇ5'˛6222˛'4˘8(9˛(˜˚˛&˙˙˙˙˙

Comment: `import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('Downloads/th.pdf','rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print (page_content)
`

Comment: Strange, I was testing it on the PDF I have that also include bold and underlined text. Maybe your issue is due to subsetted (not embedded) font in your PDF file. Try using PdfToolBox https://www.callassoftware.com/en/products/pdftoolbox

Comment: [Try this pdf](http://164.100.79.153/judis/chennai/index.php/casestatus/viewpdf/280647)

Comment: I need to extract without using any tools for that. Is there any other way to read the PDFs.